# Smarty date formats?

Tags: php, date, formatting, smarty

I am building an rss feed.

I need to output a date,
I am passing though a date that the date_format function can understand, but I am not sure how to format the date so it fits with the RFC 822 standard.

I need to output a date like this: Tue, 10 Jun 2003 09:41:01 GMT

What format should I use, or is there another modifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [PHP docs for DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
const string RFC822 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
```

The corresponding Smarty string should be `"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"`.

Comment: Ah thank you I always have trouble converting these darn things!

Comment: in Smarty3 you can use `date()` syntax as well. in fact, you could register the DateTime class and accessing that const directly…

Comment: FYI, Smarty3 [date_format](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl)